# How to fill up this python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to fill up this python list.

```
volume = []
for x in range(0,num_days):
    volume[x] = quotations(x).Volume
```

I get the error `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. What is wrong with the code and how to fill up `volume` list? `quotations` is an object imported from `win2com`.

I am using python v3.6

Comment: Use list.append(), in this case volume.append(....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the list to dict

```
volume = {}
for x in range(0,num_days):
    volume[x] = quotations(x).Volume
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `append` as indexing is for setting indices to certain values:

```
volume = []
for x in range(0,num_days):
   volume.append(quotations(x).Volume)
```

Comment: It's *indexing*. Singular *index*, plural *indices*.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you don't need to "fill up" the list as you would do in static languages like C. The size of the list is automatically managed by the language itself. Lists in Python are called lists and not arrays for that very same reason.

```
volume.append(quotations(x).Volume) # instead of volume[x] = quotations(x).Volume
```

With that said, you can certainly change an element at a certain index if you're sure it's already assigned, which wasn't in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to construct `volume`.

```
volume = [qutations(x).Volume for x in range(0, num_days)]
```